# Inserting into multiple tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do i insert into the following tables at once?

```
Table1 : table1id, name, table2id, detail
Table2: table2id, type, table1id
```

I could insert into table1 with following query

```
insert into table1(table1id, name, table2id, detail)
values
(newID(), a, newID(), null);
```

But how do i insert these news id's which got created recently in table1 into table2?

Comment: Create an insert trigger after insert

Comment: In SQL, the language, INSERT works only on one table. You can use a trigger to insert rows in the related table, or you can write multiple INSERT statements to insert the rows you want explicitly

Comment: Capturing values inserted can be done with an [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) clause.

Comment: You do have foreign key in both table, kind of circular dependency. If it is One-One relation you should have foreign  key only in one table either. Then insert into first table use @SCOPE_IDENTITY to get recently added key and use in other insert.

Answer (score 0):

direct Output into the 2nd table or composable dml

```
create table Table1Test (
table1id uniqueidentifier, 
name varchar(100), 
table2id uniqueidentifier,
detail int)


create table Table2Test
(
table2id uniqueidentifier,
type varchar(100),
table1id uniqueidentifier
);
go

--output into 2nd table
insert into Table1Test(table1id, name, table2id, detail)
output inserted.table2id, '??', inserted.table1id into Table2Test(table2id, type, table1id)
select top 2000 newid(), name, newid(), abs(checksum(newid()))
from master.dbo.spt_values;

select *
from Table1Test as a
join Table2Test as b on a.table1id = b.table1id;
go

truncate table Table1Test;
truncate table Table2Test;
go

--composable dml
insert into Table2Test(table2id, type, table1id)
select table2id, type, table1id
from
(
insert into Table1Test(table1id, name, table2id, detail)
output inserted.table2id, '??' as type, inserted.table1id 
select top 2000 newid(), name, newid(), abs(checksum(newid()))
from master.dbo.spt_values
)as src;


select *
from Table1Test as a
join Table2Test as b on a.table1id = b.table1id;
go


drop table Table1Test;
drop table Table2Test;
go
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use output clause to achieve the same.

The code will look like-

```sql
insert 
    into table1 (tab1id, name)
output inserted.tab1id, null 
    into table2(tab2id, detail)
values (newID(), 'a');
```

Insert has single memory resident table named inserted
Delete has single memory resident table named deleted
Update has both memory resident table named inserted and deleted.

You can use output clause with insert, update, delete and merge statement.